# How to dynamically change grid column sortable?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use ext 4.2. So I have grid with columns and I have to dynamically set columns sortable...
I have tried this method in grid

```
setColumnsSortable: function(sortable){
    for(var i in this.columns){
        this.columns[i].sortable = sortable;
    }
}
```

but after disabling sorting there is arrow which has to disappear...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see this link
http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/5aKdc/3/

```
grid.store.sorters.clear();

grid.view.refresh();
```

it says that you have to refresh your grid after disabling sorting

Comment: tnx a lot* you really help